# Is "Phantom Rouge" story canon?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Simply that: did the events of Hunter x Hunter: Phantom Rouge really happen (with respect to HxH story, of course)? At least the timeline is credible (between Yorknew City and Greed Island arcs).

Answer (score 5):

It's a part-canon side-story.

[AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=9323):

> The premise of the movie is **based off a manuscript of the Yorknew City arc** written by Togashi Yoshihiro that he eventually **ended up scrapping**.

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter#Phantom_Rouge):

> The film is based on an **unpublished** story manga creator Yoshihiro Togashi wrote around 10 years ago.

Since it's based off his own work, *Phantom Rouge* presumably has Togashi's blessings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is, it hasn't been confirmed by the mangaka but there is a manga chapter about Kurapika's past that is shown in the movie.